# When adding new jobs in kue, is there a way to avoid duplicates?

Tags: node.js, kue

I have a process that creates a new batch of jobs at a fixed interval (every minute) and I want to send them to kue for processing by another process.

Sometimes, the same job can be in different batches.

What happens if a job that was sent in a previous batch wasn't completed by the time it is sent again in a new batch ?

My understanding is the it will be treated as a new job and executed twice.

Is this correct, and is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing would be to trap the job `complete`event and traverse the list of queued job (doing as explained in this [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669306/how-to-retreieve-jobs-with-specific-status-in-kue))to remove a possible duplicate assuming that you can identify it.

I have never done that myself and, if you follow this route, be wary of race conditions: I wonder if it is possible that the duplicate job might be scheduled before you finish traversing the pending jobs (I do not know).

Hope this helps.